# What philosophy would believe that nature does not tell us of what should be it only tells of what is?

Tags: epistemology

What would be the philosophy that best describes the idea that nature does not tell us what should be it only tells us what is?

I have heard it as a criticism on evolutionary psychology.

.

Comment: The quote sounds like a rephrase of David Hume’s is-ought observation. An internet search did not bring up this exact wording.

Comment: [Is–ought problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem):"*The author proceeds for some time in the ordinary way of reasoning... when of a sudden I am surprised to find, that instead of the usual copulations of propositions, is, and is not, I meet with no proposition that is not connected with an ought, or an ought not... and am persuaded, that this small attention would subvert all the vulgar systems of morality, and let us see, that the distinction of vice and virtue is not founded merely on the relations of objects, nor is perceived by reason*", Hume.

Comment: I would say that the distinction of vice and virtue is founded on human reactions to people's behavior. Nature isn't involved.

Comment: Giving a quote and asking the source is kind of weird. Where did *you* get it?

Comment: From [Biblical hermeneutics](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/nature-can-teach) on what nature can’t teach: *The New Testament also maintains that nature testifies to the difference between the Creator and the creature...natural law would never direct someone to sacrifice himself for a person who didn’t deserve it. It would never teach self-sacrifice with no earthly reward in view. But God shows his love for us in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. The gospel does not contradict the natural law, but it does go above and beyond it, and in this we find our salvation...*

Comment: I have made an edit in an attempt to improve the question.